# container moving while decreases the browser window

Tags: html, css

i am using a container made by myself, but, when i resize the browser window, the container moves along window, i want it static in your place.

this is the CSS:

```
.container {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 1000px; /* yes, because style of PSD file. need follow design */
}
```

Comment: `margin:auto` will center block elements, which is why it moves. give it a static margin like `margin-left:100px` and it will not move.

Comment: my div is not a block, if i set "display: block" then, it can work?

Comment: did u set your div to a different CSS entity? because by default all divs are block elements.

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle example or give some context. What is wrapping your container? Are you using a bootstrap responsive layout?

Comment: not. without bootstrap, only normalize.css from boilerplate.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show the html that corresponds with your `.container` (is `<body>` the parent?), and the CSS for any elements that `.container` is wrapped in

Comment: OK. here are jsfiddle.net/vH49a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin: auto` centers the `.container` based on the width of its parent element.

`.container` has a parent element with a fluid width (e.g. 100%). The width of this element changes when you resize the window, so your container will automatically recenter according to that new width.

There are a few solutions to this:

1) Wrap `.container` inside an element with a fixed width that won't change on browser resize.

CSS:

```
.wrapper-fixed-width {
    width: 500px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper-fixed-width">
    <div class="container bg">The parent element has a fixed width (pixels)</div>
</div>
```

2) Set a fixed margin size to `.container`

CSS:

```
.container {
    margin: 0 50px;
}
```

Here is a JS Fiddle that shows these examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/vH49a/4/

Comment: i tested here your code and work. thanks girl. you're sweet. (is really a girl right?) joke. thanks!